# Trigonometrical solution of complex equation

Tags: complex-numbers, roots

Need present in trigonometrical form the solution of the complex equation:

$x^6 = 1 + \sqrt3 + (1-\sqrt3)i$

To take out the coefficients of the real & imaginary parts

real part: $1 + \sqrt3$, imaginary part: $(1-\sqrt3)$

Now, for converting into polar form, $r = \sqrt8$; but the other part of finding the appropriate angle representing the coefficients is not possible.

Any hint will be most welcome.

Comment: Draw it on a graph!

Comment: $$\arctan\frac{1-\sqrt{3}}{1+\sqrt{3}}=\arctan\left(\sqrt{3}-2\right)=-\frac{\pi }{12}$$

Comment: In Mathjax ALL the expression goes between $...$. Look at my edit :)

Comment: @JihoonKang: But, how to show the graph if I make it. Should I upload on a free image hosting site?

Comment: @jiten no need to do that, if you see a right angled triangle you're (probably) on the right track!

Comment: @Raffaele: I am unable to get the angle form to be used in the polar representation, so please elaborate some more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you know that $\cos\theta=\frac{1+\sqrt3}{2\sqrt2}$ and that $\sin\theta=\frac{1-\sqrt3}{2\sqrt2}$. Therefore, $2\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)=-\frac12$, which means that $\sin(2\theta)=\sin\left(-\frac\pi6\right)$. This suggests (and it is easy to prove) that $\theta=-\frac\pi{12}$. So$$x^6=2\sqrt2\left(\cos\left(-\frac\pi{12}\right)+\sin\left(-\frac\pi{12}\right)i\right).$$Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thanks for the insight. It is easy now to apply De-Moivre's theorem to find the roots.